# Updates imageView of my adapter in android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I want to use AsyncTask to have images of articles which is in the cache or in the net. After that put these images in the corresponding imageView of my adapter.
Here are my code:

**Article.java**

```
public class Article {

    private String titre = "";
    private String auteur = "";
    private String date = "";
    private String contenu = "";
    private String url = "";
    private Bitmap photo = null;

    public Article() {
    }

    public Article(Context context, String titre, String auteur, String date,
            String url, String contenu) {
        this.titre = titre;
        this.auteur = auteur;
        this.date = date;
        this.contenu = contenu;
        this.url = url;
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.no_image);
        this.photo = image;
    }

    public String getTitre() {
        return titre;
    }

    public String getAuteur() {
        return auteur;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getContenu() {
        return contenu;
    }

    public Bitmap getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setTitre(String titre) {
        this.titre = titre;
    }

    public void setAuteur(String auteur) {
        this.auteur = auteur;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setContenu(String contenu) {
        this.contenu = contenu;
    }

    public void setPhoto(Bitmap photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}
```

**ArticleAdapter**

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Article> articles;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Resources mResource = null;

    public ArticleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Article> articles) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.articles = articles;
        this.mResource = context.getResources();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return articles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return articles.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ligne, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            holder.mAuteur = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.auteur);
            holder.mTitre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titre);
            holder.mContenu = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contenu);
            holder.mDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Article a = (Article) getItem(position);
        if (a != null) {
            if (a.getPhoto() != null)
                holder.mImage.setImageBitmap(a.getPhoto());
            holder.mAuteur.setText(a.getAuteur());
            holder.mContenu.setText(wrapWord(position));
            holder.mDate.setText(a.getDate());
            holder.mTitre.setText(a.getTitre());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private String wrapWord(int pos) {
        String retour = "";
        String val = mResource.getString(R.string.size_article_list);
        int n = Integer.valueOf(val).intValue();
        Article article = (Article) getItem(pos);
        String a = article.getContenu();

        if (a.length() > n)
            retour = a.substring(0, n) + "...";
        else
            retour = a;

        return retour;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView mImage;
        private TextView mTitre;
        private TextView mContenu;
        private TextView mAuteur;
        private TextView mDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: So your question is "How can I load the images in an AsyncTask and update the Adapter with the loaded image"?

Comment: I can neither see a question nor see any description of what does not work and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I found my problem.
I have created a interne class of my adapter and extended AsyncTask. Now if i call it on getView i can update my imageViews. here are the code

public class ArticleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private ArrayList<Article> articles;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Resources mResource = null;
private static final int SIZE = 5 * 1024*1024;
private DiskLruImageCache imageCache = null;
private ViewHolder mViewHolder = null;

public ArticleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Article> articles){
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.articles = articles;
    this.mResource = context.getResources();
    this.imageCache = new DiskLruImageCache(context, "ArticleList", SIZE, CompressFormat.JPEG, 70);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return articles.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return articles.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public ViewHolder getViewHolder(){
    return mViewHolder;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ligne, null);
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mViewHolder.mImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        mViewHolder.mAuteur = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.auteur);
        mViewHolder.mTitre = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titre);
        mViewHolder.mContenu = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.contenu);
        mViewHolder.mDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    }else{
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Article a = (Article)getItem(position);
    if(a != null){
        if(mViewHolder.mBitmap != null){
            a.setPhoto(mViewHolder.mBitmap);
        }
        if(a.getPhoto() != null) mViewHolder.mImage.setImageBitmap(a.getPhoto());
        mViewHolder.mAuteur.setText(a.getAuteur());
        mViewHolder.mContenu.setText(wrapWord(position));
        mViewHolder.mDate.setText(a.getDate());
        mViewHolder.mTitre.setText(a.getTitre());
        mViewHolder.mUrl = a.getUrl();

        new ImageTask().execute(mViewHolder);
    }

    return convertView;
}

private String wrapWord(int pos){
    String retour = "";
    String val = mResource.getString(R.string.size_article_list);
    int n = Integer.valueOf(val).intValue();
    Article article = (Article)getItem(pos);
    String a = article.getContenu();

    if(a.length() > n) retour = a.substring(0, n)+"...";
    else retour = a;

    return retour;
}


public class ViewHolder{
    private ImageView mImage;
    private TextView mTitre;
    private TextView mContenu;
    private TextView mAuteur;
    private TextView mDate;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private String mUrl;
}

public class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, ViewHolder>{
    Bitmap image = null;
    @Override
    protected ViewHolder doInBackground(ViewHolder... holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder ele = holder[0];
        String key = ele.mUrl.replace("http://", "").replace("/", "_").replace("?", "_").replace(".", "_");
        if(imageCache.containsKey(key)){
            ele.mBitmap = imageCache.getBitmap(key);
        }else{
            try {
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new URL(ele.mUrl));
                image = ImageResizer.decodeSampleBitmap(bytes, 400, 400);
                ele.mBitmap = image;
                imageCache.put(key, image);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return ele;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ViewHolder holder){
        if(holder.mBitmap != null) holder.mImage.setImageBitmap(holder.mBitmap);
    }

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncHttpClient method to get the photo from the net then in the onSuccess method you will handle the setter for the ImageView.
Read about AsyncHttpClient and how to use it to get the photo

for example you can create class for HTTP Requests like the following

```
public class MyCLient{
  private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
  public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler           responseHandler) {
     client.get(url, params, responseHandler);
 }

 public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
     client.post(url, params, responseHandler);
 }
```

}

then inside your adapter, you will call the get method to get image like the following:
    MyCLient.get("your url", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONArray timeline) {
                // read the image and set your ImageView.
            }
        });

If you cannot access your activity inside your adapter, you just need to define instance variable inside your adapter class "Activity myActivity = null;" then pass your activity as input parameter to the adapter contractor and use it to set myActivity then your can use myActivity inside onSuccess method.

Comment: OK thank but i don't know how to get the reference of the correct imageView on my activity.I can make it on my Adapter but make this give an exception NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: super-qua It is  exactly the thing that i want to do but how can i do to get the references of these differentes imageView on my Activity

Comment: excuse me meredrica for my wrong question. My question is exactly the one that super-qua know : "How can I load the images in an AsyncTask and update the Adapter with the loaded image"